# How to display number of rows imported in the SSIS Send Mail Task

Tags: ssis, sendmail

In SSIS, I want to send a mail stating the number of rows imported by a "Data Flow Task".

How can I get the number of rows imported in the "Send Mail Task"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906547) covers what you're after in the enclosed example, using a variable and a row count transform, together with an expression for the mail subject (body would be similarly do-able).